# RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (20x27 and 3x30)

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

I am new to AI and have followed a tutorial to build a machine learner which predicts championship game scores. I have completed the tutorial but when I go to run the code, I get a run time error which just says mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied. I have looked through all the code and cant seem to find an issue with it. Does anyone know why this error is coming up? This is the code for the program:

```
import pandas
import torch
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

filepath = "2010_training.csv"
df = pandas.read_csv(filepath)



extract = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 13, 14, 16, 17, 18, 20, 21, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 35, 
 36, 37, 38, 47, 48, 49]
 df = df.iloc[:, extract]

training = df.iloc[:-20]
test = df.iloc[-20:]

for e in range(len(training.columns) - 3): 
num = max(training.iloc[:, e].max(), test.iloc[:, e].max())
if num < 10:
  training.iloc[:, e] /=10
  test.iloc[:, e] /=10
elif num < 100:
  training.iloc[:, e] /=100
  test.iloc[:, e] /=100
elif num < 1000:
  training.iloc[:, e] /= 1000
  test.iloc[:, e] /=1000
else:
  print("Error in normalisation! Please check!")


training = training.sample(frac=1)
test = test.sample(frac=1)

training_input = training.iloc[:, -3:]
training_output = training.iloc[:, -3:]
test_input = test.iloc[:, :-3]
test_output = test.iloc[:, -3:]

def convert_output_win(source):
  target = source.copy()
  target['new'] = 2
  for i, rows in target.iterrows():
    if rows['win'] == 1:
      rows['new'] = 1
    if rows['draw'] == 1:
      rows['new'] = 0
    if rows['defeat'] == 1:
      rows['new'] = 0
   return target.iloc[:, -1]

training_output = convert_output_win(training_output)
test_output = convert_output_win(test_output)

class Net(torch.nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size):
    super(Net, self).__init__()
    self.input_size = input_size
    self.hidden_size = hidden_size
    self.fc1 = torch.nn.Linear(self.input_size, self.hidden_size)
    self.relu = torch.nn.ReLU()
    self.fc2 = torch.nn.Linear(self.hidden_size, 1)
    self.sigmoid = torch.nn.Sigmoid() 
    
  def forward(self, x):
    hidden = self.fc1(x)
    relu = self.relu(hidden)
    output = self.fc2(relu)
    output = self.sigmoid(output)
    return output

training_input = torch.FloatTensor(training_input.values)
training_output = torch.FloatTensor(training_output.values)
test_input = torch.FloatTensor(test_input.values)
test_output = torch.FloatTensor(test_output.values)

input_size = training_input.size()[1]
hidden_size = 30


model = Net(input_size, hidden_size)
criterion = torch.nn.BCELoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr = 0.9, momentum=0.2)

model.eval()
y_pred = model(test_input)
before_train = criterion(y_pred.squeeze(), test_output)
print('Test loss before training', before_train.item())

model.train()
epochs = 5000
errors = []
for epoch in range(epochs):
optimizer.zero_grad()
y_pred = model(training_input)
loss = criterion(y_pred.squeeze(), training_output)
errors.append(loss.item())

print('Epoch {}: train loss: {}'.format(epoch, loss.item()))
loss.backward
optimizer.step()

model.eval()
y_pred = model(test_input)
after_train = criterion(y_pred.squeeze(), test_output)
print('Test loss after Training', after_train.item())

def plotcharts(errors):
errors = np.array(errors)

plt.figure(figsize=(12, 5))

graf02 = plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
graf02.set_title('Errors')
plt.plot(errors, '-')
plt.xlabel('Epochs')

graf03 = plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
graf03.set_title('Tests')
a = plt.plot(test_output.numpy(), 'yo', label='Real')
plt.setp(a, markersize=10)
a = plt.plot(y_pred.detach().numpy(), 'b+', label='Predicted')
plt.setp(a, markersize=10)
plt.legend(loc=7)
plt.show()

plotcharts(errors)
```

Comment: I'll assume that `input_size=20x27`

Comment: Please, update with the complete traceback. They are useful.

Comment: `actual input` and model `definition input` is not matching

Comment: Okay so what do I need to do to rectify the error? The dataset is the issue?